# mssql query sum one field among other fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to achieve something like this:

```
SELECT AttendDetails.Date,AttendDetails.AttendId, NameCode,PhoneNo,Patients.
[Next of Kin] as NextOfKin,Company,
ConsultFee,LabFee, XraFee as XrayFee, ECGFee,
AdmitFee,SUM(PresFee) AS TotalPresFee,MedFee,TheaterFee,ScanFee
FROM AttendDetails
LEFT JOIN Patients on AttendDetails.OPDNo = Patients.OPDNo
LEFT JOIN [Company list] on [Company list].AcNum = AttendDetails.GLOffset
LEFT JOIN ConsultDetails on  AttendDetails.AttendId = 
ConsultDetails.AttendId 
LEFT JOIN LaboratoryDetails on AttendDetails.AttendId = 
LaboratoryDetails.AttendId
LEFT JOIN XrayDetails on AttendDetails.AttendId = XrayDetails.AttendId
LEFT JOIN ECGDetails on AttendDetails.AttendId = ECGDetails.AttendId
LEFT JOIN AdmitDetails on AttendDetails.AttendId = AdmitDetails.AttendId
LEFT JOIN PrescripDetails on AttendDetails.AttendId = 
PrescripDetails.AttendId
LEFT JOIN Medicals on AttendDetails.AttendId = Medicals.AttendId
LEFT JOIN TheaterDetails on AttendDetails.AttendId = TheaterDetails.AttendId
LEFT JOIN ScanDetails on AttendDetails.AttendId = ScanDetails.AttendId
WHERE AttendDetails.GLOffset = $P{company}  
AND AttendDetails.Date BETWEEN $P{startDate}  AND $P{endDate}
GROUP BY <something>
```

where one of the fields in the result is a SUM value. But i seem to not be getting the group by clause right. Or am I doing it all wrong??

Comment: What is the error you get? Are you grouping by all selected fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During an aggregate query, all fields need to be either part of the GROUP BY clause or affected by an aggregate function. In this case, since you're only aggregating one column, your group by must be all remaining fields:

```
GROUP BY
    AttendDetails.Date,
    AttendDetails.AttendId, 
    NameCode,
    PhoneNo,
    Patients.[Next of Kin],
    Company,
    ConsultFee,
    LabFee, 
    XraFee, 
    ECGFee,
    AdmitFee,
    MedFee,
    TheaterFee,
    ScanFee
```